# Simple game - hangman

Tags: java, beginner, hangman

Recently I made simple [hangman game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game).) in Java.

Main.java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a passwords");
        String word = input.nextLine();
        char[] password = word.toCharArray();
        char[] passwordView = new char[password.length];
        for (int w = 0; w < passwordView.length; w++) {
            passwordView[w] = '_';
        }

        int badAnswers = 0;
        char letter = 'x';
        String guess;
        boolean success;
        String answers = "";


        while (badAnswers < 11) {
            success = false;
            System.out.println("Type a char.");
            while (!success) {
                guess = input.nextLine();
                if (guess.length() == 1 && !(answers.contains(guess))) {
                    letter = guess.charAt(0);
                    success = true;
                    answers = answers + letter + ", ";
                } else if (!(guess.length() == 1)){
                    System.out.println("Type exactly one char!");
                }
                else if (answers.contains(guess)){
                    System.out.println("You have already typed that symbol!");
                }

            }

            CheckingIfPasswordContainsLetter checker = new CheckingIfPasswordContainsLetter();
            if (checker.cointans(password, letter)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
                    if (password[i] == letter) {
                        passwordView[i] = letter;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                badAnswers++;
                System.out.println("Bad");
            }

            if (!(Arrays.equals(password, passwordView))) {
                System.out.println("Already used symbols: " + answers);
                System.out.print("Current password is ");
                new PrintingArray(passwordView);
                System.out.print("\n");
            }


            if (Arrays.equals(password, passwordView)) {
                System.out.print("You won! the password was ");
                new PrintingArray(password);
                break;
            }

            if (badAnswers == 11) {
                System.out.print("You lose! Sorry!");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

PrintingArray.java

```
package com.company;

public class PrintingArray {

    public PrintingArray(char[] a){
        for (char z : a) {
            System.out.print(z);
        }
    }

}
```

CheckingIfPasswordContainsLetter.java

```
package com.company;


public class CheckingIfPasswordContainsLetter {
    public boolean cointans(char[] a, char b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == b) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         for (int w = 0; w < passwordView.length; w++) {
>             passwordView[w] = '_';
>         }
> ```

There's a built-in for this

```
        Arrays.fill(passwordView, '_');
```

You don't have to do it manually.

> ```
>         char letter = 'x';
>         String guess;
>         boolean success;
> ```

You could declare all these inside the loop instead by changing

> ```
>             success = false;
>             System.out.println("Type a char.");
>             while (!success) {
>                 guess = input.nextLine();
>                 if (guess.length() == 1 && !(answers.contains(guess))) {
>                     letter = guess.charAt(0);
>                     success = true;
>                     answers = answers + letter + ", ";
> ```

to

```
            char letter;
            boolean success = false;
            System.out.println("Type a char.");
            while (!success) {
                String guess = input.nextLine();
                if (guess.length() == 1 && !(answers.contains(guess))) {
                    letter = guess.charAt(0);
                    success = true;
                    answers = answers + letter + ", ";
```

or even better, get rid of `success` entirely.

```
            char letter;
            System.out.println("Type a char.");
            while (true) {
                String guess = input.nextLine();
                if (guess.length() == 1 && !(answers.contains(guess))) {
                    letter = guess.charAt(0);
                    answers = answers + letter + ", ";
                    break;
```

or consider something like

```
            char letter = inputLetter(input, answers);
```

with a properly defined method.

> ```
>                 new PrintingArray(passwordView);
>                 System.out.print("\n");
> ```

You don't need `PrintingArray`, but you could just say

```
                System.out.println(passwordView);
```

and get the same effect.

> ```
>             CheckingIfPasswordContainsLetter checker = new CheckingIfPasswordContainsLetter();
>             if (checker.cointans(password, letter)) {
> ```

You don't need this either.  You could just say

```
            int firstOccurrence = word.indexOf(letter);
            if (firstOccurrence >= 0) {
                for (int i = firstOccurrence; i < password.length; i++) {
```

This also has the side effect of not duplicating the scan.  Note that the original version started over at the beginning.